# Big Project indexing with Eclipse [Locally]

Tags: eclipse, indexing

I have a C based very big project (more than 200,000 source files) and I want to index it using eclipse.

Earlier, there was an issue with a memory problem and I change .ini file to assign 3GB of ram.

Still, I cannot index it. the project stuck indexing at any point. sometimes at 2 % and sometimes 60%.

Kindly suggest a way or may be another tool which can be useful.

I can compile and run it separately as well. all I need right now is proper indexing of the project.

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse.ini , try following options : -Xms1G -Xmx4G